# DMN to AST convertor

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, dmn

I need a tool that can validate and parse given DMN text and convert it into AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)
Does anybody know about DMN to AST converter except kie-feel?
The parser should recognize range and default operators like =.

I tried kie-feel but it is not able to parse range properly.

Comment: "I tried kie-feel but it is not able to parse range properly." you should mention what you tried, what was not working with expected behaviour.

Comment: It is not recognizing range and default operators (example: =) so it could not produce proper AST. It is also not able to validate incomplete expressions.

Comment: The first one, sounds like a but, you should report it https://github.com/apache/incubator-kie-issues/issues
The latter is because it does not expose the ANTLR internals and the KIE FEEL expect a complete expression for evaluation; sounds like instead you need access the ANTLR internals for relying on that Antlr capability